# Какой знак препинания поставить: А я говорю() было!

Tags: пунктуация

Что поставить:
"- Там ничего не было! - А я говорю() было!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А я говорю - было!

БСП со значением изъяснения, тире заменяет классическое двоеточие в предложениях подобной структуры.